# Get command line arguments from Electron Application that is already running?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Currently I need to get command line arguments from an Electron application. So if you start the application with command line arguments, I need to use the arguments within the renderer process (a webview to be specific.)

This works fine when opening the application for the first time (using onload), but I'm having issues getting this to work when the application is already running and the user tries to reopen the app from cmd with args.

Currently, I'm using:

```
let closeDupeApp = app.makeSingleInstance(function(commandLine, workingDirectory) {
    // Someone tried to run a second instance, we should focus our window.
    if (mainWindow) {
        if (mainWindow.isMinimized()) mainWindow.restore();
        mainWindow.focus();
    }
});
```

To prevent a second window from opening. However, I need the commandLine arguments and I need to send them to the renderer process.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Did you do a search on this? Anyway you can get command line arguments from the global variable `process`. The property name is `argv`. You can read `process.argv` anytime to get the relevant data.

Comment: Process.argv doesn't help me. I need to send the arguments to the renderer process upon attempting to launch the application. The provided method is the only way I have found to detect such an occurrence. I need a way to send commandLine to a renderer function upon it happening.

Answer (score 3):

You can read `process.argv` in the main process and paste it onto the end of the file:// url as a query string in `BrowserWindow.open()`. I do this routinely. You can JSON encode the and `encodeURIComponent` on the array to get a nice list in the renderer process.

Answer (score 3):

Found a solution:

main.js

```
let closeDupeApp = app.makeSingleInstance(function(commandLine, workingDirectory) {
    if (mainWindow) {
        // Send args to renderer
        mainWindow.webContents.send("cmdArgs", commandLine);

        if (mainWindow.isMinimized()) mainWindow.restore();
        mainWindow.focus();
    }
});
```

rendererFile.js

```
require('electron').ipcRenderer.on('cmdArgs', function(event, cmdArgs) {
    // STUFF
}
```